# How can I use image inside Xcode 11 playground?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-playground, swiftui, xcode11

I am doing the SwiftUI tutorial which is on the Apple's website in Xcode 11 playground because I use Mojave and not Catalina. There is an image called turtlerock.jpg, but it doesn't show in the playground.

I put the  image inside the resource folder, but no luck.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I've been scratching my head over this problem too. I've managed to find at least a workaround for now:

Instead of:

```swift
Image("turtlerock")
```

try:

```swift
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "turtlerock.jpg")!)
```

You'll have to have turtlerock.jpg in the Resources folder of your playground. If you turn it into a .png first, you can use `UIImage(named: "turtlerock")` in the above.

Comment: A further workaround to make it a bit cleaner in the rest of the code...
`extension Image {
    init(res: String) {
        self.init(uiImage: UIImage(named: res)!)
    }
}`
Then call like this...
`Image(res: "turtleneck.jpg")`