# SwiftUI Image is not showing up in Swift Playground on macOS using Xcode 15

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift-playground

I have a Swift Playground in Xcode 15 that has a file structure as follows:

```
|-.swiftpm/
|----Resources/
|    |----cat.png
|    |----plane.png
|    |----train.png
|----MyApp.swift
|----ExampleView.swift
```

In `ExampleView.swift`, I had Xcode (using "+" button) to help me insert the Image:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ExampleView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Image("cat.png")
    }
}
```

But the image would not show on preview, I also tried:

```
Image(uiImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cat.png"))
```

and

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "cat.png")!)
```

As suggested in the answer of [How can I use image inside Xcode 11 playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513762/how-can-i-use-image-inside-xcode-11-playground) and [How do we display an image in a SwiftUI playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63859613/how-do-we-display-an-image-in-a-swiftui-playground)
However, both of them crashed during preview and removing `.png` extension does not work either.
What can I do next?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I use image inside Xcode 11 playground?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56513762/how-can-i-use-image-inside-xcode-11-playground)

Comment: @HangarRash As mentioned, `Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "cat.png")!)` did not work.

Comment: have you tried `Image("cat")` or `Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "cat")!)`, without the `.png`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Yes, as mentioned in the question: **removing .png extension does not work either**

Comment: ok, did not see/read that bit. Does this post help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63859613/how-do-we-display-an-image-in-a-swiftui-playground

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine No, in the first try **I had Xcode (using "+" button) to help me insert the Image**, and it generated `Image("cat.png")`. Also, using `UIImage` would crash anyway

Comment: What's the `.swiftpm` folder that you show? I ran Xcode 15.2. Did File -> New -> Playground. Under iOS I picked Blank. I opened the sidebar. On the Resources folder I right-clicked and selected "Add Files to Resources...". I selected a png file. Once there I used your code with the `Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "myAddedImage")!)` line and the image showed up just fine. Using `Image("myAddedImage")` resulted in a blank white view.

Comment: Of course I also need to add `PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = UIHostingController(rootView: ExampleView())` so the view would appear.

Comment: @HangarRash the .swiftpm is the root of the playground, or shouldn't I list that as a folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that when I was adding the image file, I added it under the folder "Resources" and didn't work. Added it to the root folder for the second try, Xcode created `Assets.xcassets` in the project, and it worked.